# Find area of latitude/longitude bounding box offline in python

Tags: python, geo

I want to find area of latitude/longitude bounding box in square meters. 
I need to do this quickly, that's why the solution should be offline.

Comment: postgis has python bindings, has it not?

Comment: @latheiere: that yields a lot of shit. Not wrong to ask for some pointers. You can google anything, if you just-know-the-name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually use [Shapely](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Shapely) for this kind of tasks. 
However... this particular problem is not as easy as it looks, since you would need to transform your lat/lon data to a more appropriate projection.
You can use [pyproj](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyproj/) for that.